# VSCode multiple versions of custom snippets

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating custom javascript snippets in VS Code. I have a snippet that creates a React component class, but using the same prefix, I want to have a slightly different version of the react component class. This is my code:

```
   "Creates a React component class": {
        "prefix": "rcc",
        "body": [
          "import React from 'react'",
          "",
          "class ${1:className} extends React.Component {",
          "    render() {",
          "        return (",
          "            <div>",
          "",
          "            </div>",
          "        )",
          "    }",
          "}",
          "",
          "export default ${1:className}"
        ],
        "description": "Creates a React component class"
    },
```

I want to type rcc and have it give me two options, one is default, and the other pastes this code:

```
   "Creates a React component class": {
        "prefix": "rcc",
        "body": [
          "import React from 'react'",
          "",
          "class ${1:className} extends React.Component {",    
          "    render() {",
          "        const runCallback = (cb) => {",
          "            return cb()",
          "         }",
          "        return (",
          "            <div>",
          "",
          "            </div>",
          "        )",
          "    }",
          "}",
          "",
          "export default ${1:className}"
        ],
        "description": "Creates a React component class"
    },
```

Comment: give the other the prefix `rcc2`

Comment: There is something called "choices" for VS Code snippets. I looked at the documentation and was confused on how to implement it. I know there's a way though. Just need some help

Comment: choices don't allow you to enter a whole lot of text (multiple lines), with almost similar prefixes you get both in the suggest list, then pick the one you want

Comment: That makes more sense. I guess I'll have to make two different snippets. Thanks for the information!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without choices:

```
  "Creates a React component class": {
  "prefix": "rcc",
  "body": [
    "import React from 'react'",
    "",
    "class ${1:className} extends React.Component {",    
    "    render() {",
    "        ${2:const runCallback = (cb) => {\n\t\t\t\t\treturn cb()\n\t\t\t\t\t\\}}",
    
    "        return (",
    "            <div>",
    "",
    "            </div>",
    "        )",
    "    }",
    "}",
    "",
    "export default ${1:className}"
  ],
  "description": "Creates a React component class"
}
```

`choices` do not appear to allow returns in them, but a default option does.

If you don't want the default option, just <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> twice when it is selected.

If you want it <kbd>tab</kbd>.

[image: jsx class snippet]

Comment: Thanks so much! I want to understand how this works. What are the /n and /t for? What does each of them do, and why so many?

Comment: `/n` is a return - so newline.  `/t` are tabs - a few of them to get the indentation you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to realize you cannot do this at this scale. The choices feature in VS Code custom snippets, only allows you to chose between a couple one-line words in your code.

It looks like this:

```
${1|choice1, choice2|}
```

Comment: you can edit your question,